# How to print register's values in c++ program?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm using the g++ compiler and I'm attempting to print all of the registers along with their values (without modifying them).

I've read a lot online about assigning values to registers and performing operations on them, but nothing about reading values of registers from a process.

Can anyone explain this in detail to me as well as the flags that would be used with the g++ compiler?

Comment: You need to use debugger for that, not compiler. And if you use g++ for compiling then probably you should use gdb.

Comment: @Slava I'm trying to write a program that requires it know what registers are used by the processes. Possibly including accumulators, index registers, stack pointers, general purpose registers, etc.

Comment: Outputting the content of all registers might be a similar problem to singing a song while holding your breath.

Comment: "it know what registers are used by the processes." What processes? You want to dump registers from other processes?

Comment: I have no idea what the question is about... want to write a debugger from scratch? If printing registers on current execution state of own process, the registers must be saved before the printing code modifies all registers... but all of that is unclear... time to vote to close please!

Comment: In *standard* C++, you can't reliably print the values of a register.  The compiler may not use registers, it could place values in memory instead.  The compiler can switch registers to a function that returns a register (think inline assembly).

Comment: @Yunnosch: To be fair, "not modifying" usually really means "restoring any that you *do* modify".  So you don't have to *hold* your breath, just exhale into a bag (the stack) and re-inhale that air later :P.  In asm it's certainly possible to write a `dump_regs` function, and Irvine32 has one.  Calling it from C would disturb code-gen of surrounding code, though, because the compiler doesn't know about the no-clobbers calling convention.  Calling it from inline `asm volatile` could maybe work, at least in an ABI without a red-zone, or if you work around that...  But yeah, use a debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes True. Nice going with my simile.